# Android detect unsuccessful phone call and try again later

Tags: android, kotlin, telephonymanager, android-audiomanager, phone-state-listener

Is there a way to retry a missed or unsuccessful outbound phone call after a period of time? I am initiating a phone call using the `ACTION_CALL` intent and have it connected to a PhoneStateListener.

```
class PlaceCall : AppCompatActivity() {
    private fun outboundCall() {
        val telephonyManager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
        telephonyManager.listen(CallListener(context), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE)
        val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber))
        startActivity(callIntent)
    }
}
```

CallListener is setup like this:

```
class CallListener(cont: Context) : PhoneStateListener() {
    private var context: Context = cont
    private var incoming: Boolean = false
    private var prevState: Int = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE

    override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, phoneNumber: String?) {
        val audioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        when(state) {
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING -> { incoming = true }
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                if(prevState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) { //Missed call?
                }
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK -> { Log.d("DEBUG", "calling $phoneNumber") }
            }
        }
        prevState = state
    }
}
```

How can I wait a determined interval and try the call again if it is anything other than a successful phone call connection? Also, why is the value of `phoneNumber` in the listener always empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike an incoming call which goes through `IDLE` -> `RINGING` -> `OFFHOOK`,
in outbound calls it always jumps directly from `IDLE` -> `OFFHOOK` even while it's ringing (on the other side).

So if by "successful" you mean to say a phone call that had been picked up by the other side, `PhoneStateListener` won't help you, as there's no additional state sent when the other side picks up.

> Also, why is the value of phoneNumber in the listener always empty?

`phoneNumber` is populated for incoming calls only, and only if you app has both `READ_CALL_LOG` and `READ_PHONE_STATE` permissions, [see here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER).

If you need to last called number you can use the [`Calls.getLastOutgoingCall`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls?hl=en#getLastOutgoingCall(android.content.Context)) API a few seconds after an outgoing call has ended.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer @marmor! Yes, by a "successful" phone call I am referring to actually having the person being called answer the call. This would mean a missed call, voice mail, or no answer would be considered unsuccessful. Sounds like there is no way to detect this within `PhoneStateListener`. Is there a way to achieve this elsewhere?

Comment: there's no API that I know to achieve this, however I know there are some call recording apps, which suggest you might have access to the call's audio itself, which you might use to detect whether a call had been picked up or not... sounds a bit overhead though

Comment: Is there a way to detect when the phone call terminates via the `PhoneStateListener` or within the `PlaceCall` class? Would `startActivityForResult` work?

Comment: yes, you'll get the IDLE state again when a call terminates